# What can be moved safely to tmpfs in 14.04?

Tags: laptop, 14.04, ssd, tmpfs

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop with SSD and 8gb RAM. What can be moved safely to tmpfs(and how to do it correctly, i'm mediocre in linux)? I don't know is it important or not, I mounted anything to / (i did not create separate partitions for home or something like that). Also, maximum RAM usage I saw is about 1.5-2 gb.

Comment: You shouldn't care about this. Tmpfs is a system-purpose fs. Or if you insist, you may put there anything you don't hurt if lost.

Comment: Why do you want to move anything to `/tmp`? Anything you put there will be deleted next time you restart. What is your actual objective here? Do you want to clear some space?

Comment: I guess it can reduce writing to ssd.

Comment: You can do things like putting your browser profile in tmpfs: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/keep-your-browser-profiles-in-tmpfs-ram.html